# How to sync my iCloud email acct using the stock email app?

Tags: applications, email, stock-email-app

I am using cyanogenmod11 on both my phone and tablet which comes with AOSP email app. I've also tried the latest stock email app that Google released recently on the playstore.

No matter what I do, I can't get my email. The server settings (both imap and smtp) validates fine but nothing happens.

I've looked at various guides available in the net. They are very much the same. The settings used are the same.

I have tried K-9 mail app using the same settings and that works fine retrieving my data. So I believe I'm using the correct settings.

Any ideas what I could set in the stock email app?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried the cloud magic email app yet? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudmagic.mail

Comment: if I were to use a third party app, I would use K-9 as I know that works. I'm asking on how to make it work on Google's email app. thanks :)

Comment: This should solve your problem http://www.androidcentral.com/how-set-your-icloud-email-account-android http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4864

Comment: that's one of the guides that I used. Works for K-9. but not for the stock email app (both AOSP and the one from the playstore). And I've also seen the Apple link. The guides I've seen like the one from Android Central uses SSL/TLS for smtp but it never worked for me. But following the Apple suggestion of using STARTTLS works. As I said, both email and K-9 validates my server settings fine. Except only K-9 retrieves my data.

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4864 ?